# Help changing Title Format

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I managed to find this code snippet somewhere a while back which made my chapter titles look fancy:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{\resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{7cm}{1.5cm}}}
{10pt}{\huge\bfseries\raggedright}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
```

Which makes my titles look like this:

[image: Chapter Zero]

Which is great. The only problem is, when it comes to two digit chapters, I end up with this:

[image: Chapter Ten]

Where the thing on the right is a bit too short for my liking. I don't fully understand the code since I got it from some template site which I can't recall. I tried playing around with the parameters in the code but I didn't manage. Here's a minimal working example if anyone wishes to compile it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec, graphics,geometry,lipsum}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}

%Chapter Headers
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{\resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{7cm}{1.5cm}}}
{10pt}{\huge\bfseries\raggedright}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Logic}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't achieve what you want with a right margin of only `1 in`.

Comment: @Bernard Unless it pushes back into the text block area? I can't figure out how to do that, but it would probably look strange in any case. (Which I guess is your point.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overlapping only the `\thechapter` + `\rule` construction. That means, the wider the `\thechapter`, the less of the `\rule` construction will be visible. You may want to move the content - which should include the reference to `\chaptertitlename` to the left.

I've applied the above suggestion by using [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s overlapping tools:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,geometry,lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}

%Chapter Headers
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\adjustbox{lap=.7\width}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{7cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\huge\bfseries\raggedright}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{8}

\chapter{Logic}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Logic}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

You'll notice the black block changes size since the positioning is based on the width of "`\chaptertitlename` + `\thechapter`". If you want a fixed black block, you could consider something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,graphicx,geometry,lipsum}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}

%Chapter Headers
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\mbox{}\rlap{\hspace{.5in}\llap{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter}} \rule{7cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\huge\bfseries\raggedright}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{8}

\chapter{Logic}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Logic}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want? `Titlesec`has its own switches: `\filleft,\filright,\filcenter`, instead of `\raggedright,\raggedleft`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec, graphics,geometry,lipsum}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, showframe}

%Chapter Headers
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large}
{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
{\resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{7cm}{1.5cm}}}
{10pt}{\huge\bfseries\raggedright}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Logic}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]